# Как в базу MySQL занести результат из дробным подсчетом?

Tags: delphi, mysql

Вопрос в следующем: как в базу `MySQL` занести результат из дробным подсчетом?
например если `b:=2;` все правильно заносит, если `b:=0.4;` то результат 0 будет.

поле ПЕНСИЯ в базе имеет тип `DOUBLE`

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    var b:real;
    begin
    b:=0.4;
     //b:=2;
    with sqlquery1 do
    begin
    active:=false;
    sql.Clear;
     SQL.Add('UPDATE base SET пенсия="'+edit8.Text+'"*"'+floattostr(b)+'"');

     ExecSQL;

    end;
```

Comment: * [eng](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries)
* [рус](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/delphi_sql_queries.html)

Comment: подсказка номер два.

Исторически сложилось, что для разделения целой и дробной части используют разные символы. Иногда даже в пределах одной сущности. Ваша программа скорее всего будет работать на английской локали.

подсказка номер три.

Составлять запросы, делая явную конкатенацию, нужно осторожно. Для составления запросов давно придумали параметры.

Comment: ниодно ни второе ни третье из выше перечисленного здесь непричем, потому как на самом деле он умножает на 0,4 а нужно на 0.4, вот и второй вопрос как сделать что бы b был 0.4?

Comment: вот как раз второе именно то, что вам нужно. Дам еще от себя подсказку [decimal separator][1]


  [1]: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=DecimalSeparator

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, да что вы [говорите](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Global_Variables)

Comment: @LLIAKAJI предупреждаю в первый раз: повежливее...

Comment: навскидку :
`sql.Clear;Sql.Add(..)` <=> `sql.Text:='';`

Comment: Barmaley, обязательно постараюсь делать низкий поклон при каждом комментарии, вводимое сообщение начинать с большой буквы, и не ковыряться в ухе, не знаю что вам там привиделось, но с моей стороны небыло ниодного ругательского слова не говоря уже о чем то более

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь компонентами UNIDAC. Тогда поля в ДБ будут выглядеть как переменные в дельфи. И вы сможете "напрямую" их редактировать. Но там несколько приколов есть. Рассказывать не буду. Сами прочтете в хэлпе.